# Check URL for string in a Twig file

Tags: theming, 8

I'm new to twig and drupal 8 and finding it hard to access page titles. I want to apply a class to a page title on certain pages, all of which share a sub-directory in the URL path. I'm working with a page-title.html.twig file and want to do something like this:

```
{{ title_prefix }}
{% if title %}
  {% if <url contains "/services/"> %}
    <h1 {{ title_attributes.addClass('services-title') }}>{{ title }}</h1>
  {% else %}
    <h1 {{ title_attributes.addClass('page-title') }}>{{ title }}</h1>
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
{{ title_suffix }}
```

I'm assuming this is possible, I just can't figure out how to check the URL for the desired string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the "in" operator:

```
{% if '/services/' in url %}
```

More information: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#containment-operator

If you didn't do it already, put this preprocess function in the file `mytheme.theme` in your theme directory:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {
  $variables['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url.path';
}
```

**Edit:**
By moving the code from page inside a block we need to provide a cache context.

Comment: I've done this and the 'if' statement is executing with no errors, but always evaluates to false, even on the '/services/' pages. So I end up with 'page-title' no matter what. Any idea what is going wrong? I did create the .theme file and replaced 'mytheme' with the correct theme name and cleared the caches.

Comment: do I need to be escaping those slashes in '/services/' perhaps?

Comment: I've just put the complete code from my answer in a page template, it works, with slashes. You don't need to escape them. Be sure, that the preprocess sets the var 'url'.

Comment: {{ url }} isn't returning anything. I did not have a .theme file before, should that be declared in one of the yml files or something?

Comment: I added an echo $variables['url'] to the .theme page and that works and outputs a relative path starting wtih /services/ so somehow it's getting lost between the prepocess function and the twig file. (and yes it has <?php)

Comment: I found it, we are in different templates, you are using `page-title`, my code is for `page`. You have to move php and twig in the same template.

Comment: tried using preprocess_page-title in the theme file and that seems to prevent the twig file from working at all. non-services pages look fine, but do not even get the 'false' class added to the title now. services pages are completely blank white pages of death. nothing but <html><body></body></html>

Comment: I also tried moving the page-title twig stuff into page.html.twig and getting ride of page-title.html.twig altogether. It seems to ignore everything completely that way and doesn't assign any classes at all. It seems like working with the page-title template is required, I just need the correct syntax to do that in the .theme file.

Comment: The theme hook is `page_title` with an underscore, you have to use this name for the preprocess.

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly. Thank you so much. Might be worth adding the _title to the answer.