# How do I get a URL variable in a template?

Tags: theming, 8

I am trying to include a certain .html file if the URL has ?work=1.

So far I have this, which I got from 
[Check URL for string in a Twig file](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197062/check-url-for-string-in-a-twig-file).

```
 {% if 'work' in url %}
    {{ include('work/index.html') }}
 {% endif %}
```

They say I need a function in my .theme file to actually get the URL variable.
Is that right? Is there any way to get it with just Twig?

Comment: Have you inspected `url` to make sure it actually has the query string in it? There's a chance it won't, definitely worth checking. Re the variable existing or not - it completely depends what template it is and what vars it already has available. Sorry to be vague but it's hard to be more specific without more information about the problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok nevermind. On the other stack I mentioned the function was

```
function riptide7_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {
  $variables['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url.path';
    echo "What?!";
}
```

and I just had to change preprocess_page_title to preprocess_page